# Github desktop not allowing push to github repository owned by myself

Tags: git, github, github-desktop

I connected my gitHub repository to gitHub desktop and have it running through IntelliJ. Everything works fine on IntelliJ; it allows me to add files and class no problem. Then when I update and and commit it to the local branch it is fine. Then when I go to the gitHub Desktop I can see the changes appear. The problem is when I go to push the updates. It throws this error message:

> Authentication failed. You may not have permission to access the
>   repository or the repository may have been archived. Open options and
>   verify that you're signed in with an account that has permission to
>   access this repository.

The thing is when on GitHub I clicked the option to open the project on GitHub Desktop and when I look in options it gives me the option to sign out. I am so confused about the error.

Answer (score 1):

You might have added restrictions to your GitHub project (e.g. you need to go through pull requests before pushing some commits). To check those out, go to `<repo.url>/settings/branches` to see your branch rules.

Otherwise, have you logged in with your github app? Is it the same profile as the owner of the repo? If not the owner, are you a collaborator?

If it is a public repository, you probably have to [fork](https://help.github.com/en/articles/fork-a-repo) it, in order to work on it.

Otherwise, try this :

```
$ cd path/to/my/repo/
$ git push
```

It should ask for your GitHub credentials if you cloned it through HTTPS.

If the error persists, you should probably clone your repo through the GitHub Desktop app to be sure that the Git configuration files match what is needed to interface with your GitHub repository.

Comment: @Levi If that answer worked for you, consider accepting it by using the green checkmark next to it. Thanks!